# Changing color of the candlestick inside marked area in Echarts

Tags: javascript, charts, echarts

I have created a candlestick chart using Echarts version 5.4.3. I have created 2 mark areas between 0-10 and 30-40. I would like to make the candlestick red inside marked area like this:
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9zJZ.png)
Here is my code:

```
option = {
  xAxis: {
    data: ['A', 'B', 'C']
  },
  yAxis: {},
  visualMap: [
      {
        show: true,
        type: 'piecewise',
        seriesIndex: 0,
        pieces: [
          {
            gt: 40,
            color: '#c37976',
            color0: "#c37976",
            borderColor: undefined,
            borderColor0: undefined
          },
          {
            gt: 10,
            lte: 30,
            color: '#808080',
            color0: "#808080",
            borderColor: undefined,
            borderColor0: undefined
          },
          {
            lte: 10,
            color: '#c37976',
               color0: "#c37976",
            borderColor: undefined,
            borderColor0: undefined
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
  series: [{
      type: 'candlestick',
      data: [
        [38, 15, 38, 15],
        [40, 20, 40, 30],
        [0, 15, 0, 15],
      ],
       itemStyle: {
            color: "#808080",
            color0: "#808080",
            borderColor: undefined,
            borderColor0: undefined
          },
       markArea: {
        itemStyle: {
          color: 'rgba(255, 173, 177, 0.4)'
        },
        data: [
          [
            {
              yAxis: 40
            },
            {
              yAxis: 30
            }
          ],
          [
            {
              yAxis: 0,
            },
            {
              yAxis: 10
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
  }
      ],
        graph: {
    color : "rgb(128,128,128)",
  }
  
};
```

Could you help me?
Thank you so much in advance.

I tried using the visual map however it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VisualMaps do not work the way you think here. The visualMap is applied to the whole series item if the condition is met, not just to the part which meets the condition.

I think the best way to achieve what you are trying to do is the follwoing:

- use multiple [stacked bar series](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.stack)
- the first series represents the space between 0 and the start of the data item
- the second series represents the space of the data item inside the lower markedArea (if any)
- the third series represents the space of the data item inbetween the markedAreas
- the fourth series represents the space of the data item inside the upper markedArea (if any)

Each series can be styled individually this way. Here is an [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-waterfall&code=MYewdgzgLgBANiA7gUwE4CEQFcwBMYC8MAjAAwDcAUKJLFgA71qY75EDMF140MuAhlH4AlfmADmyCIRgBtWcQCsAGhjsAHAF1VsgEylVAFlLa5Bkos2aqlAPS2YoALb0sUZH0H8Y_VKn4AnjAAZiCoMMj8wAAWMBBoAJZSdg7EAHQwCWAAbgkQ_ABGcB5uCXAJUEEFvnFYMTBQ0YIwuflFHtWo0tC-sM2NyAnhqFJMwFAJ2R49qLDZ_HBYyCkwuhn0vTAgwQ3RHTWI0Qn1eTCsaPBIzNh4K-zrm9u7--GHx7GnWQXIUCjIYJcUBgbvgxPgGExgawVoYHrMtjsBjBOjA3idpIUQFMzoxrtDgjhxglwI4QC43MgACJeAAUAiEogkUgAlDAAN6UGCk2ieIQyeSmWSC4XWTkwMWhcI0mi8fxMhG8kRiSQQVkcrlcmWwen8YgyOWSWQmKgaxVGzRpVwQaJ0rzEZkmjVirnFbVeXQyLimhI7GkG5DmmAAHkBeLwaudGp1HqICCBLDwMAAtDB_ebHVyAL6RnUKC1Wm3Rh2RyOuxXsGQAWUE0TSTiyNIhYdwqjTxE0rJT1cadf4AA8aXHm63lQGTMXTbndPmsNbbUJ2BOnaayzrDJ6M5lfW3NDAAHw4yEJ3AR01ctf60d55OH5ub7OTryydgzudrpcP8VckZQLCoAE6lQ2bcDyOoyM4rjuNSQjzkqTKqjYID0BMJJEOqMB9gAgn2eQAFzspGlRMPhADkwCCMg4hhAEJHKDmXj4bIJGYbRMAkegrEkQAwiRmhipmdFcgE2F4QRppEcgpHzIsyAkfxdFivEqBJBAjGRuhppgPwTiSWxMwTBIMD0CAWRQLRkZchJpGdOZZ5xEIwAANakT0Tm2WeFTIE4ADKlTFPhGlngUYS4GgXEgAgqCkVAcoQBsIxgGZgl2aSkXRbF8X_GZFkwAJOUQGUWX4TFSzJY-Qj4bmJhlRqTi-I5mEjPwAU5Vynk-X5umBXZoBpWxqDiNUNK6IoKgkAA7OwqjEON42qKQaSGMyckpblNXlc1citRqshssJOGqTAxgCey-2iU2UJ4Jm2jbVyu1nYdpAnXtImHUOl24Nd218XZn5ZjV3UwFpOmke9yIgu54kBMRbE2et9lRM5ekOY5kNRgxZrtvD7W-QE_nsr1YSkQAxMA7DjQAnONABsJF_Wt6k5cDukkV8Px_GAaOWdDLNw_lKMuSjXOKpVT7Ttj7gdXjXWE1FbHE-opCK4rdORnlpqA8zpEXeDrDC1ZsO-MLrlIyRJvCzqotCM-N12TjnUBbLJNk5TNOq6an58Zm5BAA):

```js
const lowerBound = 10;
const upperBound = 30;
const dataRanges = [[15, 38], [20, 40], [0, 15]];

// compute data array for each series
// 1. invisable utility bar such that visable bars start at their respective start value
// 2. part of the bar which is under lowerBound
// 3. part of the bar which is inbetween lowerBound and upperBound
// 4. part of the bar which is above upperBound
function computeData(dataRanges) {
  const data = [[], [], [], []];
  
  for (const range of dataRanges) {
    const data1 = range[0];
    data[0].push(data1);
    
    let data2 = 0;
    if (range[0] < lowerBound) {
      data2 = lowerBound - range[0];
    }
    data[1].push(data2);
    
    let data3 = Math.min(upperBound, range[1]) - Math.max(lowerBound, range[0]);
    data[2].push(data3);
    
    let data4 = 0;
    if (range[1] > upperBound) {
      data4 = range[1] - upperBound;
    }
    data[3].push(data4);
  }
  
  return data;
}

const data = computeData(dataRanges);

option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['A', 'B', 'C']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },

  series: [
    {
      name: 'starting point',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'stack',
      itemStyle: {
        borderColor: 'transparent',
        color: 'transparent'
      },
      silent: true,
      data: data[0],
      markArea: {
        itemStyle: {
          color: 'rgba(255, 173, 177, 0.4)'
        },
        data: [
          [{yAxis: 40}, {yAxis: upperBound}],
          [{yAxis: 0}, {yAxis: lowerBound}]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'lower bound',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'stack',
      data: data[1],
      itemStyle: {color: '#c37976'}
    },
    {
      name: 'inbetween',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'stack',
      data: data[2],
      itemStyle: {color: '#808080'}
    },
    {
      name: 'upper bound',
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'stack',
      data: data[3],
      itemStyle: {color: '#c37976'}
    }
  ]
};
```

Note, that the current implementation only works for data items >= 0 and you might run into difficulties if you want to use [tooltip](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#tooltip) (which might be solvable by adding more utility series).

---

**EDIT:**

Here is a solution for an arbitrary number of areas which works also for negative values. Note, that the code is not very pretty.

[Exmaple](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-waterfall&code=MYewdgzgLgBAJgQyggSgsBzAphGBeGAbUIEYBWAGhgGYAOAXSsIFoSA2KkhpgBk7MZFm1CgHZBhapRiiBTVtOE969ANwAoUJFgIATlgS4CxZpRLKm1PjAAsFoQCZrrBxNHWAnMrXr1AMwBXMGAoAEtwGAAbEAB3ABUQADFQ3WgABRAIULDwAApI0OgAShgAb3UYGD8QXRhcrWgYbKwAWxgQPyjCqBLyysrQztzmlsJlGAAeAhHSehKtMLAArA1-mAr-hthomKxa6ahW2dX-mZJ6fCbD0eUTgeuxi4IdvZOAX3UPnYTk1KgMrI5MC5RDINCYHBFDTfJIpdKZbLhYF6AwQKG-AD0GJgEBqOn0hhg6DgMAwuhAAQADk0wFAQDBKQiwgA3LBEsAksBYDBIUKszTgRpcnksrAAQQJRiIPi2DKZfPFksuhB81Vq9UF-IM7U6KMMvQ2gzqesekxgPBgADJLUSCbMYAA-c0GtaMwEKiWogB0lICEAAFrkxlQTec5ncYMLeazPYYfX7A4QTfZlOjKm8YFhIhA2UbcsmLg6CDwXf03YiY5L4wH8wS0zAM1mc00hqGLlNnWUNpUo6LYxBq4G9fWPh9ex6q7jdFBcvmqAAjEp4J3z03MImPdHlvuTvGzhALpdOhBrmCr1MaXyynO6UI4AAiSAQl1Kbw0arqst06GwOvgT_BbA0S7SpIiwWBmQQSJlkuHgTjzb8IVNJ0SxgSDoLZAhEOwR4TgQOA4AAeV0ABJMBslyAByaA9CgAB9N1KKodDlnrDYWMw814KGbCsHtCZOw4y5eOODZ8KI0jyJnajkGnOjhSYtCoNYk4NixOV3VZW1UQ2MDtkMKBY1gk4Pw1bQaTgLAAA8aQ0itFVRUtKllPVLm3CdUUIUIOWsnw1m7JSMOMgKEJ_PjxgEgsrRtETzkdKIDNjJz-iEggAFkkH9L0Wm82sDEeKhYrmGB1wyqAspaBArPyRKCUKsLNwjD41nE4iyIoyigks3RKJgABqCzrP6mBKIYxSOPrSoAoC1KuJCniGoi7STzi60YCK-KC2SypZrKircrbeqkPOEpSsy7Kqryk97BEi8Aua_pWskjrvPncDdiwMBeoG7zLJsgbRspcblKwSb1jWdSIAAa1Cal5z0dasEpfQc1pbyMH_ZASOuIl5xALTyrZVyjWyXAwBAWBCYSxpwCwea6gAOQCFo3t0YYfKskoBpIfA8AIdzK29MDMHK7bApg4sAoGBbjsLZbZjFnaQeEhq4rO8qLuqw71sW8MpYbfWnva6SEDx1lvsG_6RrGqgSya6a1kiWrtQINt3g2NTsXHLS9QgXTnefYsTJqT9NUt2zvYc_UQM2MPXIISP-y8jm_P6GblaD-nclu9tqcMglop12XNrtE6Y7WXbzsqrXS8EHPTpgPbstyp3oFjI6cJO-2WoItqpKo038awC3fqGgH5OBjCwYdlKM7mtZQqQpa20LjbjztVNy9noL0qry6Cw78LivV_bkVrw-Fe7x7e-e6TXverBPpHjnhtGr7mJB6eIexaHYbPBH9DIxwJ9RYGNQQIGxq0GAXU9gwCpsTTopNIwUzgf6NkrdYC0yzkzFmex2Z_S5jAHmfME7cmjFHAcwsMCiy3krHe881gtjqDnM0W1aHbwlkXHC4wT7NzPvlG6qs9aMINiIo2_dOo-R6sNUeVs36TxUvdGeoEA6XALO7T4vhAjBCBESG-xtchQywAATw_lPGOeYbx3ggI-ZAhAjHGKeHzaBPk_DeSwHAZKViHxPnsSYp4RAOKp0bNmNkfR-jeJsb4hx9BBy5Amu7D4V4w6VV0FDfsypVQhzMo0VyHRlrAXCak9JVZfQ1kIKUYxYorKFAAFzy2UG8KglTql1PlucN4esknXj2NYgAMt0TJGhIkDOgHE8JYAEAtCwPUmStF0Zym8rAAWw8KAbCgMYykMyRrwx6msyoNFgBQ1mYxfZVxWgAGUNlgXqeEyoeNdDdQAMIgGiLoWZUBEIQEpCiWkTEAqgDeR8r5Pz9B_I2E0jYWRhZQHqZ85YZzwH1MibYk8cy5KMUYBsYpsZbkhWuFc4xNz2GApqLM3QGB4a5AcGQaQJBRAiCIaIUQtsvQ2CKJRe6ZzKhIpgDiyUZzIX3L0AAcQQJSeprBPjoksnpNkKLfHovopiy8IzujjI2JM6ZsyaLTgWYyJZkYyGin-ZUDZWzZm7NNTiZARzZkKTOSMQlxK7lnhqM815ZKRqfPQN835UBrXOU9e871IL_WcvTGc6FIC4W6ARRsXlCq7FKvktySiWLKj8oMHiheBLrnbNdUGoFI0KVUppXShlnBmWsvZRG_oQr-i8qzYYQV0qNCyvAvK3pPjk26vogpHw_hsmygcX-Qi84ABWWAQhegcRAXISaEBFFLHpGApL9gjQAMS0B4DundlFuJ1AcV6bywBoKWXnZRe-UAPpfWXWu4NlxKKbuANQUQHhRBsAPR7UC4EbUICOU-xih7DEmJPcEc9OAqIT3vYcqGT6FKqQOd2iAoyoAarWOa7ZlErXcv_Xa_DUM8OJpQ6ivxji8NOvzbc9d9T10PTeOiJJ6gQCUl0QQcJVlWkQBzf0LDszgBIG5DUYx1qG1VJqTxre_GRocTrQ2yJyKUNoc-KoIAA):

```js
const dataRanges = [[15, 38], [-16, 18], [0, 15], [-3,7], [35, 75], [-15, -30]];
const areas = [[-5,10], [30, 40], [-20, -12], [70, 90]];

function lowToFirstPosition(list) {
  for (const item of list) {
    if (item[0] <= item[1]) continue;
    
    const lower = item[1];
    item[1] = item[0];
    item[0] = lower;
  }
}
lowToFirstPosition(dataRanges);
lowToFirstPosition(areas);

// sort areas and group into positive and negative
const negativeAreas = [];
const positiveAreas = [];
for (const area of areas) {
  if (area[0] < 0 && area[1] > 0) {
    positiveAreas.push([0, area[1]]);
    negativeAreas.push([area[0], 0]);
  } else if (area[0] >= 0) {
    positiveAreas.push(area);
  } else if (area[1] <= 0) {
    negativeAreas.push(area);
  }
}
negativeAreas.sort((a, b) => b[0] - a[0]);
positiveAreas.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);


const seriesData = {};
for (const range of dataRanges) {
  let value = 0;
  if (range[0] > 0) value = range[0];
  addOrInit('start_pos', value);
  
  value = 0;
  if (range[1] < 0) value = range[1];
  addOrInit('start_neg', value);
  
  // positive areas
  let lastArea = 0;
  for (const index in positiveAreas) {
    const area = positiveAreas[index];
    
    value = 0;
    if (range[0] < area[0] && range[1] > lastArea) {
      value = Math.min(area[0], range[1]) - Math.max(lastArea, range[0]);
    }
    addOrInit('under' + index + '_p', value);
    
    
    value = 0;
    if (range[0] < area[1] && range[1] > area[0]) {
      value = Math.min(area[1], range[1]) - Math.max(area[0], range[0]);
    }
    addOrInit('inbetween' + index + '_p', value);
    
    // skip bar representing dataItem above the area if its not the last one
    if (Number(index) + 1 === positiveAreas.length) {
      value = 0
      if (range[1] > area[1]) {
        value = range[1] - Math.max(area[1], range[0]);
      }
      addOrInit('above' + index + '_p', 0);
    }
    
    lastArea = area[1];
  }
  
  // negative areas
  lastArea = 0;
  for (const index in negativeAreas) {
    const area = negativeAreas[index];
    
    value = 0;
    if (range[0] < lastArea && range[1] > area[1]) {
      value = Math.max(area[1], range[0]) - Math.min(lastArea, range[1]);
    }
    addOrInit('above' + index + '_n', value);
    
    
    value = 0;
    if (range[0] < area[1] && range[1] > area[0]) {
      value = Math.max(area[0], range[0]) - Math.min(area[1], range[1]);
    }
    addOrInit('inbetween' + index + '_n', value);
    
    // skip bar representing dataItem under the area if its not the last one
    if (Number(index) + 1 === negativeAreas.length) {
      value = 0;
      if (range[0] < area[0]) {
        value = range[0] - Math.min(area[0], range[1]);
      }
      addOrInit('under' + index + '_n', value);
    }
    
    lastArea = area[0];
  }

}

function addOrInit(key, value) {
  if (seriesData[key] === undefined) {
    seriesData[key] = [value];
  } else {
    seriesData[key].push(value);
  }
}


const markAreas = [];
for (const area of areas) {
  markAreas.push([{yAxis: area[0]}, {yAxis: area[1]}]);
}

const seriesList = [];
seriesList.push({
  name: 'starting point positive',
  type: 'bar',
  stack: 'pos',
  itemStyle: {
    borderColor: 'transparent',
    color: 'transparent'
  },
  silent: true,
  data: seriesData['start_pos'],
  markArea: {
    itemStyle: {
      color: 'rgba(255, 173, 177, 0.4)'
    },
    data: markAreas,
  },
  barGap: -1
});
delete seriesData['start_pos'];

seriesList.push({
  name: 'starting point negative',
  type: 'bar',
  stack: 'neg',
  itemStyle: {
    borderColor: 'transparent',
    color: 'transparent'
  },
  silent: true,
  data: seriesData['start_neg'],
  markArea: {
    itemStyle: {
      color: 'rgba(255, 173, 177, 0.4)'
    },
    data: markAreas,
  }
});
delete seriesData['start_neg'];

for (const key of Object.keys(seriesData)) {
  let color = '#808080';
  if (key.includes('inbetween')) color = '#c37976';
  
  let stack = 'pos';
  if (key.includes('_n')) stack = 'neg';
  
  seriesList.push({
    type: 'bar',
    stack: stack,
    data: seriesData[key],
    itemStyle: {color: color}
  });
}


option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: seriesList
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I would like to use the chart for the negative values also do you have any tips on how I can achieve that?

Comment: Not quite as easy I think. You would need to adjust the `computeData` function to work properly for negative values and then add at least two more series. 1. for an invisable utility bar representing the space between possible negative data and 0 and 2. for representing the negative data.

Comment: I will try to improve your solution. On the other hand, in this example (https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-sections) they used visual map for making a red line between areas. This is working because this is a line chart not a candlestick am I right? If I use line chart it will work that's my understanding.

Comment: Generally the visualmap will be applied to the whole data item which meets the condition. In a line series each point is a data item. In a bar or candlestick series each bar / candlestick is one data item.

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution that should work for negative values too.